# How to search for multiple sub-strings in a single query

Tags: javascript, regex, indexof

I've come across a point from which I am unable to think further. 
Briefly, I have an `ul` with hundred of `li`, each `li` having tens of words as text; at the very top of the list I have put an input box for the user to type some keywords; let's say, for example, that I want to filter out from that huge list only the lines where the following three words exist in the same line: "**red sweet strawberries**". Being hit the search button, the lines are filtered out and there I have only two rows containing the words I am interested in.

li1: "I hardly wait to eat some **red sweet strawberries**"

li2: "It is summer and the **red sweet strawberries** are fresh now"

Until this point everything is fine.

The problem occurs when the three looked up words are separated by other words or characters along the string.
So, taken the upper example, the filter would never show me the following line:

li3: "The **red** and **sweet strawberries** are on the market now"

So, here I lay down the entire function that filter and sort out the results from the upper example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var links = new Array();
      $("h4").each(function(index, element) {
      links.push({
            text: $(this).text(),
            element: element
        });
    });

    $("#searchbutton").click(function() {
        var query = $("#inputtext").val();
        var querywords = query.split(',');

        var results = new Array();
        for(var i = 0; i < querywords.length; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
                if (links[j].text.toLowerCase().indexOf(querywords[i].toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                    results.push(links[j].element);                    
                    }
            }
        }

        $("h4").each(function(index, element) {
            this.style.display = 'none';
        });
        for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            results[i].style.display = 'block';
        }

    });     

});
```

Is it possible to search for multiple sub-strings and get results, even if the sub-strings are separated by characters or other words ?

Comment: In the first for-loop shouldn't `querytext` be `querywords`?

Comment: Yes, querywords. I have updated ! On this forum I 've just changed all the "querytext" to "querywords" (for emphasize the roles of words in my example)and I have skipped that one. Thanks. Still this is not the cause.

Comment: MikeM. I have tried your code to suit my function, but unfortunately and due to my bad understanding of RegEx syntax I have not been able to make it work. Right now I am learning what is all about this RegEx. Thanks again for your code.

Comment: Apologies, I had missed off the text and element property look-ups that I hadn't needed when using the code in testing. I have updated the code and added a link to a working JSFIDDLE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way of doing what I think you want.

```
var results = new Array();
for ( var i = 0; i < querywords.length; i++ ) {
    var regex = new RegExp( 
        '(?=.*\\b' + querywords[i].split(' ').join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + '\\b)', 'i'
    );
    for ( var j = 0; j < links.length; j++ ) {
        if ( regex.test( links[j].text ) ) {
            results.push( links[j].element );
        }
    }
}
```

For example, if `querywords` contained the item `"red sweet strawberries"`, the `regex` created would be

```
/(?=.*\bred\b)(?=.*\bsweet\b)(?=.*\bstrawberries\b)/i
```

Three positive [look-aheads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) are used so that strings which contain the three words on the same line pass the test (if they are surrounded by a word boundary).

Demo: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MWTtU/1/).

Comment: That's an awesome work, MikeM ! Your solution must be on the top search query for this issue around google search. I see now that indexOf is very limited for a broader search function. Thank you very much for your effort... Regards !

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correctly, the whole problem is:

```
var querywords = query.split(',');
```

In the example query you have no comma. So i guess this is a mistake? Split the query with space:

```
var querywords = query.split(' ');
```

Comment: If I split with a space then the results would give me back a line with "red", a line with "sweet" and so on.

Comment: I am not looking for the user to split anything anyway as he is expecting to find a two, or a three words expression together and not splited.

Comment: But why do you split with comma? It doesn't make sense. Just split the query with space. You can simply test how many of querywords were found in each line. Add only lines where all querywords were found. Or you can sort lines by the number of found querywords. 

Do you want the querywords to be close together? Make sure that difference between returned value from indexOf is not too big.

Maybe a regular expression would solve your problem.

Comment: I think I might come close to the solution; As I have said if I split with space I get all the results where at least one word is found; If I would be able to filter then only the results where all the 3 words are found (in the same line) I would be a happy learner; So here is where I am stuck: how do I filter out and return only the lines where all 3 words are found ?

Comment: Vetvicka, how do you "add only lines where all querywords were found" ? In case the function finds all 3 words in the same sentence.